# accommodate somebody somewhere

Tags: expressions

I am writing a letter to an official body and I need to say that my friend will be staying in my flat. Is it correct to say that "I am able to accommodate my friend in my 2 bedroom flat at address" (specified above).

Comment: Writing advice is off-topic here.  However, that said, your “am able to accommodate” should just be “can house” and your “2 bedroom flat” should be “two-bedroom flat”.

Comment: Is the official body the grammar police?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not incorrect (except that as tchrist noted, *2 bedroom flat* should be *two-bedroom flat*).  It is true that *[accommodate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accommodate#Verb)* has a sense “To provide housing for; to furnish with something desired, needed, or convenient; as, to accommodate a friend with a loan or with lodgings” that applies.

Note that the phrases “I am able to” and “able to accommodate” may sound slightly stilted to American English speakers.  For U.S. usage I suggest something like “My friend can stay at my two-bedroom flat at «address»” or “My friend can stay in the other bedroom of my flat at «address»”.  People also will say “My friend can stay in my two-bedroom flat at «address»”.

Comment: The phrases “I am able to” and “able to accommodate” also sound slightly stilted to this British English speaker.